# How would I specify a window in Vim to be max height when switching to it?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

Right now when I open a new window I do `<ctrl> w n` and then I resize it with `<ctrl> w _`.

Also when switching windows I do `<ctrl> w <arrow-key>` until I get the window I want and then `<ctrl> w _` again to set it to max size.

How do I make the windows always resize to the max height when I switch to it? Is there a better way or better set of key strokes to accomplish what I am asking?

I'm pretty new to Vim so any help and suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for the so-called *Rolodex mode*:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * set winheight=999
```

This makes the current window fill most of the screen. For more information, see `:help 'winheight'`

Comment: :D :D "Rolodex mode", ingenious name for it :))

Comment: @Idigas: Credit for the name goes to Tony Mechelynck; it describes this very well indeed.

Comment: Rolodex is incredibly useful. [This page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Window_zooming_convenience) has some background.